# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null when i try remove() firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to delete a node in the firebase but when I use the remove () method an error message appears in the browser console.

First a warning:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'titulo' of null

Soon after an error:

> VM6615 firebase.js:300 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'titulo' of null

Despite the error messages the firebase is deleting the node of your database.

I'm finding it very strange why in other situations I use the remove it is working perfectly without giving log errors on the page.

Is there any way to remove a non-remove () node? Using update () or set ()?

keyCategoria, keySubCategoria, and keyDocumento are node values ​​that have been retrieved in variables.

My nodes are:

[image]

```
var documentosRef = firebase.database().ref('documentos');
var documentosCatRef = firebase.database().ref('documentos/estacionamento/categorias');
var keyCategoria= "<%= params[:key_categoria]%>"
var keyDocumento= "<%= params[:key_documento]%>"
var keySubCategoria= "<%= params[:key_subcategoria]%>"
var documento;

    function initFirebase(){
        documentosCatRef.child(keyCategoria).child('subcategorias').child(keySubCategoria).child('documentos').child(keyDocumento).on('value', function(data) {
         documento = data.val();
         $('#nomeDoc').text(documento.titulo);
         $('#titulo').val(documento.titulo);
         $('#data_inicio').val(documento.data_inicio);
         $('#data_realizacao').val(documento.data_realizacao);
         $('#data_fim').val(documento.data_fim);
        })
    }

    function initFireBaseForm(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){

            showLoader();                           

            documento = {
                titulo: $('#titulo').val(),
                data_realizacao: $('#data_realizacao').val(),
                data_fim: $('#data_fim').val(),
                data_inicio : $('#data_inicio').val(),
                categoria: $('#categoria').val(),
                subcategoria: $('#subcategoria').val(),
                arquivo: arquivo.length > 0 ? arquivo : ""
            }

            if($('#titulo').val() != "" && $('#data_realizacao').val() != "" && $('#data_inicio').val() != "" && $('#categoria').val() != null){    
                if(($('#categoria').val() == keyCategoria)){
                    subCategoryValue = $('#subcategoria').val();
                    if(($('#subcategoria').val() == 'Sem subcategoria')){
                        if(keySubCategoria == ""){
                            documentosRef.child('estacionamento').child('categorias').child(keyCategoria).child('documentos').child(keyDocumento).update(documento);
                            window.location = "/estacionamentos?estado=updated_success";
                        }else{
                            documentosRef.child('estacionamento').child('categorias').child(keyCategoria).child('documentos').push(documento);
                            documentosCatRef.child('estacionamento').child('categorias').child(keyCategoria).child('subcategorias').child(keySubCategoria).child('documentos').child(keyDocumento).remove();
                            window.location = "/estacionamentos?estado=updated_success";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });

<div id="form">

    <div class="formLine">
        <label>Título do arquivo</label>
        <input type="text" id="titulo">
    </div>

    <div class="formLine datepicker">
        <label>Data do evento</label>
        <input type="text" id="data_realizacao">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary date-set"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="formLine datepicker">
        <label>Data início</label>
        <input type="text" id="data_inicio">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary date-set"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="formLine datepicker">
        <label>Data fim (opcional)</label>
        <input type="text" id="data_fim">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary date-set"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="formLine">
        <label>Categoria</label>
        <select id="categoria"></select>
        <input type="text" id="nomeNovaCategoria" placeholder="Nova categoria..."> <i class="fa fa-times" id="closeCategoria"></i>
        <a href="#" id="novaCategoria">Nova Categoria</a>
        <a href="#" id="addNovaCategoria">Adicionar</a>
    </div>

    <div class="formLine">
        <label>Subcategorias</label>
        <select id="subcategoria"></select>
        <input type="text" id="nomeNovaSubCategoria" placeholder="Nova Subcategoria..."> <i class="fa fa-times" id="closeSubCategoria"></i>
        <a href="#" id="novaSubCategoria">Nova SubCategoria</a>
        <a href="#" id="addNovaSubCategoria">Adicionar</a>
    </div>

    <div class="formLine">
        <label>Arquivo</label>
        <input type="file" id="arquivo">
        <div id="document">
            <img src="" id="document">
            <a href="#" id="changeDocumento">Alterar</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fileLine">
        <p>Arquivos suportados: jpg, doc, docx, txt, pdf, ppt, pps, xls e xlsx.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="formLine" id="buttons">
        <a href="/estacionamentos" id="voltar">Voltar</a>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Salvar">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said to your previous post, I don't see anywhere in the code where you're dereferencing something and looking up `titulo` on it (e.g. `blabla.titulo`). Where in the code does the error come from? Alternatively, can you try and reproduce it in a site like jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: this is the problem I also do not see where the title causes the error. This title seems to come from the file itself that is already on the firebase.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i edited again. Maybe it helps to see what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, now there are lines dereferencing, such as `documento.titulo`. Once thing that could happen on that line is that `documento` is null. You can check for this by wrapping it in `if (data.exists()) { /*code that uses data.val()*/ ... }`

Comment: thanks! It's works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `documento.titulo` in some of the code, which could lead to this error when `documento` is null.

To prevent the error, you can check if the data exists in the database before trying to use it:

```
function initFirebase(){
  documentosCatRef.child(keyCategoria).child('subcategorias').child(keySubCategoria).child('documentos').child(keyDocumento).on('value', function(data) {
    if (data.exists()) {
      documento = data.val();
      $('#nomeDoc').text(documento.titulo);
      $('#titulo').val(documento.titulo);
      $('#data_inicio').val(documento.data_inicio);
      $('#data_realizacao').val(documento.data_realizacao);
      $('#data_fim').val(documento.data_fim);
    }
  })
}
```